# Two hr in one element in wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I will have menu like this. I have only text menu bootstrap & wordpress, but  i don't know how to do this two hr's

my footer -

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <!--Generowanie Górnego Menu Strony-->
        <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'            => 'footer-nav',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left footer_menu',
            'depth' => 2,
            // 'link_before'     => '<b>',
            // 'link_after'      => '</b>',
            'walker'   => new BootstrapNavMenuWalker()
          ));
        ?>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add css borders:

```css
.footer-nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.footer-nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.footer-nav ul li.active a,
.footer-nav ul li a:hover {
  border-top: 10px solid #A15180;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #A15180;
}
```

```html
<nav class="footer-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">FIRST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SECOND</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">THIRD</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```